# Show or Hide field when selected radio button codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I am currently doing a project. I have 2 radio button,1) One way 2) Round trip. When the user tried to select the One way radio button, the return text field will hide.

I've saw a thread and someone comment regarding to this problem. Scenario: I chose the One way radio button, the return field will disappear, yes it is working but there's some problem. What if I change my mind, from one way radio button to Round trip? The problem is the return field didn't came back

**View **

// my radio button

```
<div class="pure-u-1-1 radiobtn">
     <form action="">
           <input type="radio" name="flight_type"  value="one_way" class="onew" style=""  >One Way
           <input type="radio" name="flight_type" class="roundw" style="" checked>Round Trip
     </form>
</div>
```

// the return field that will hide/show

```
<div class="pure-u-1-1 dr" id="try">
      <label for="return" class="drr">Return</label>
      <input type="text" id="return" name="return" class="departreturn"><br>

</div>
```

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('change', 'input:radio[name=flight_type]', function(){
    $('div[id^="try"]').hide(); // hide all DIVs begining with "my_radio_"
    $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + '_text').show(); // show the current one
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `.toggle()`

> ## .toggle()
>
> Description: Display or hide the matched elements.
>
> With no parameters, the .toggle() method simply toggles the visibility of elements:
>
> REF: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pure-u-1-1 radiobtn">
  <form action="">
    <input type="radio" name="flight_type" value="one_way" class="onew" style="">One Way
    <input type="radio" name="flight_type" class="roundw" style="" checked>Round Trip
  </form>
</div>

<div class="pure-u-1-1 dr" id="try">
  <label for="return" class="drr">Return</label>
  <input type="text" id="return" name="return" class="departreturn"><br>

</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).on('change', 'input:radio[name=flight_type]', function() {
    $('div[id^="try"]').toggle(); // toggle all DIVs begining with "my_radio_"
    $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + '_text').show(); // show the current one
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi sir i have a question, what can I do to prevent validation that showing the "return field is required" whenever I choice the One trip?